A question on coefficient functional in Banach space with countable Schauder basis
Here is the exercise: " Let $\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ be a Schauder basis for a Banach space $X$. If $k_n\in \mathbf{K}$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|k_n|<\infty$, then there is a unique $x\in X$ s.t. $f_n(x)=k_n$ for each coefficient functional $f_n, n=1,2,...$". The book I follow defines Schauder basis in the following way:

A countable subset $\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ of $X$ is called Schauder basis for $X$ if $\Vert x_n \Vert=1$ for each $n$ and if for every $x\in X,$there are unique $k_1,k_2,...\in \mathbf{K},$ the scalar field s.t. $x=\sum_nk_nx_n.$

So, if I follow the definition, for every $x\in X$ we get unique scalars $k_1,k_2,...$, then I can say, unique scalars determine the element $x$ uniquely. Then, what else do I have to prove here, I am clueless, please help. Thank you beforehand!!!

As you noted, you will always have uniqueness, if you have existence. You still need to show that such $x$ exists.
